# Server always return 500 in IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a MVC project in React and .NET.
My server and client are running well locally. But, when I run it from IIS the server always return 500 error.

Does someone have an idea how to understand what's wrong, and why the server return 500 always?

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, try using failed request tracing to see details about 500 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem. This link provide the method to enable failed request tracing to capture the detailed error: [failed request tracing](https://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis).

Comment: Don't spam tags please. You cannot be using all of those different iis versions at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I run the application and run in local host in the server computer in order to see a verbose error information.
I did a right click on the 500-error in the network tab (after open F12) and the open in a new tab.
That's helped me understand why the server always returned 500.